# Changing permanently html values using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change a html value permanently via javascript? I'm accessing a local file.

These are my codes:

```
function switchPic(){
  top.topPage.activeDef = top.topPage.document.getElementById('h1');
  top.topPage.activeDef.href = "pic2.html";

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If by "permanently" you mean changing the HTML file (on the server), the answer is no, you cannot do that with client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Same with a local file. Javascript is not allowed file-system access for security reasons.

Comment: @sholsinger: But then, how does TiddlyWiki do that? See http://www.tiddlywiki.com/ This works at least for local files.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Javascript in the browser is insulated from the local file system (sandboxed) for security reasons.